# sendto(): Transport endpoint is not connected error while trying to send a response from server using UDP

Tags: c, networking, udp, client-server, sendto

I was trying to do simple client-server program using UDP where i'll send one string form client to server and the server acknowledge "got it". Things are working fine until i try to send the ack. The send to generates a "Transport endpoint is not connected" error.
i'm using sentto() to sent in the following format it server.

```
sendto(sid, message, strlen(message), 0, (struct sockaddr *) &saddr, len);
```

and receive from like

```
recvfrom(sid, message, 50, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &caddr, &len);
```

i'm using AF_UNIX socket. The program is working fine when i ported it to AF_INET.

Comment: Please provide a code snippet, sendto() should work here if used properly

Comment: i'm not able to add the entire code. when i use "<code></code>" it gives me an error saying to indent the code. but it is already indented.

Comment: AF_UNIX and UDP? What are you talking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use  `recvfrom()` to read from the socket and pass the received socketinformation back to `sendto()` like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in client;
socklen_t slen = sizeof(client);

int l  = recvfrom(fd, buf,      sizeof(buf), 0, &client, &slen);
int st = sendto  (fd, "got it", 6,           0, &client,  slen);
```

This should work as you expect